# Re-render does not occur when edit or delete is performed on search item

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a scoreboard that can perform CRUD operations, it does so well and re-renders well but when an item is accessed via search(not the main list but the filtred list), the details do not re-render when edit and delete is performed on an item. I.e, if the score is edited from 20 to 30 on an item in search, it should rerender as 30 without the need for a page reload, the same goes for delete. It should be removed from render without a page reload

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  deleteDetails,
  updateDetails,
} from "@/app/store/features/score/scoreSlice";
import {
  openModal,
  closeModal,
  deleteOpenModal,
  deleteCloseModal,
} from "@/app/store/features/modal/modalSlice";

export const SearchResult = ({ _id, result }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formdata, setFormData] = useState({
    name: result.name,
    exactScore: result.exactScore,
  });
  const [isEditMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  async function handleDelete() {
    const url = `https://leader-board-backend.vercel.app/api/v1/score/${_id}`;
    try {
      await axios.delete(url);
      dispatch(deleteDetails(_id));
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(deleteOpenModal());
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(deleteCloseModal());
        }, 3000);
      }, 3000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  function handleEdit() {
    setEditMode((prevEditMode) => !prevEditMode);
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = `https://leader-board-backend.vercel.app/api/v1/score/${_id}`;
    try {
      await axios.patch(url, formdata);
      dispatch(updateDetails({ _id, ...formdata }));
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(openModal());
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch(closeModal());
        }, 3000);
      }, 3000);

      setEditMode(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isEditMode ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            value={formdata.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control"
            aria-describedby="name"
          />
          <label htmlFor="exactScore" className="form-label">
            Score
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="exactScore"
            name="exactScore"
            value={formdata.exactScore}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="form-control"
            aria-describedby="exactScore"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success mt-1">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <div
          className="card text-left my-2"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
        >
          <div className="row card-body">
            <div className="col">
              <p style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>{result.name}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <p style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>{result.exactScore}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col col-lg-2">
              <button
                onClick={handleEdit}
                className="me-3 rounded-circle bg-success border border-0 text-light"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  className="bi bi-pencil-square"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z" />
                  <path
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={handleDelete}
                className="mx-3 rounded-circle bg-danger border border-0 text-light"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  className="bi bi-trash"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z" />
                  <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Slice**

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const url = "https://leader-board-backend.vercel.app/api/v1/score/";
const initialState = {
  details: [],
  isLoading: false,
};
export const getScores = createAsyncThunk("score/getScores", async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios(url);
    console.log(`SERVER DATA`);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response);
    throw error;
  }
});
const scoreSlice = createSlice({
  name: "score",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addDetails: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        state.details.push(action.payload);
      },
      prepare(name, exactScore) {
        return {
          payload: {
            name,
            exactScore,
          },
        };
      },
    },
    updateDetails(state, action) {
      const { _id, ...formData } = action.payload;
      state.details = state.details.map((item) =>
        item._id === _id ? { ...item, ...formData } : item
      );
    },
    deleteDetails: (state, action) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      state.details = state.details.filter((item) => item._id !== id);
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(getScores.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getScores.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.details = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getScores.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
});
export const isLoading = (state) => state.isLoading;
export const { addDetails, deleteDetails, updateDetails } = scoreSlice.actions;
export default scoreSlice.reducer;
```

**Others**

```js
import { SearchResult } from "./SearchResult";

export const SearchResultsList = ({ results }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      {results.map((result, id) => {
        return (
          <SearchResult key={result._id} _id={result._id} result={result} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const Search = ({ setResults }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [searchBox, setSearchBox] = useState(false);
  const searchRef = useRef(null);
  const data = useSelector((store) => store.score.details);

  const fetchData = (value) => {
    const lowercaseValue = value ? value.toString().toLowerCase() : "";
    const hasNumber = /\d/.test(lowercaseValue);
    const hasString = /[a-z]/i.test(lowercaseValue);

    if (hasNumber && hasString) {
      setError(true);
      setResults([]);
      return;
    }

    const result = data.filter((user) => {
      const lowercaseName =
        user && user.name ? user.name.toString().toLowerCase() : "";
      const exactScore =
        user && user.exactScore ? user.exactScore.toString().toLowerCase() : "";

      return (
        lowercaseName.includes(lowercaseValue) ||
        exactScore.includes(lowercaseValue)
      );
    });

    setError(false);
    setResults(result);
  };

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setInput(value);
    fetchData(value);
  };

  const handleSvgClick = () => {
    setSearchBox((prevState) => !prevState);
    setInput("");
    if (searchRef.current) {
      searchRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchBox && searchRef.current) {
      searchRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [searchBox]);

  return (
    <div className="mt-2">
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="16"
          height="16"
          fill="currentColor"
          class="bi bi-search"
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
          onClick={handleSvgClick}
          cursor="pointer"
        >
          <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
        </svg>
        <div className="ps-2 col-4">
          {searchBox && (
            <input
              type="search"
              placeholder="search"
              value={input}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
              ref={searchRef}
              className="form-control rounded-pill col-4"
              style={{ textIndent: 10 }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {error && (
        <p className="text-danger m-0 p-0">Enter number or letter, not both.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Home**

```js
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ScoreContainer } from "./components/ScoreContainer";
import { getScores } from "./store/features/score/scoreSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { PostScore } from "./components/PostScore";
import Modal from "./components/modal/Modal";
import DeleteModal from "./components/modal/Delete";
import PostModal from "./components/modal/Post";
import { Header } from "./components/Header/Header";
import { Search } from "./components/search/Search";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { SearchResultsList } from "./components/search/SearchResultsList";
import { Loader } from "./components/Loader/Loader";

export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isOpen } = useSelector((store) => store.modal);
  const { isOpenDelete } = useSelector((store) => store.modal);
  const { isOpenPost } = useSelector((store) => store.modal);
  const { isLoading } = useSelector((store) => store.score);
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getScores());
  }, []);

  const allOrSearchData =
    results.length !== 0 ? (
      <SearchResultsList results={results} />
    ) : (
      <ScoreContainer />
    );
  //
  return (
    <main className="container-lg">
      <Search setResults={setResults} />
      <PostScore />
      <Header />
      {isLoading && <Loader />}
      {allOrSearchData}

      {isOpenPost && <PostModal />}
      {isOpenDelete && <DeleteModal />}
      {isOpen && <Modal />}
    </main>
  );
}
```